# How to have a button that leads to another part of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am building a Portfolio website that will have a few sections like home, about me, skills, services, projects, and contact. I built a section of every part, then I have usually a header and some paragraph or a photo. At the center bottom of the every section I would like to have a button that leads to another section/part. So for example in the home section I wish to have a button that will direct me to another page which will be about me.

I have written a HTML code for the section and have a design in CSS, but not sure how to make, the button" work"

I don't want to have a separate HTML file for every section, this is why I am thinking if there is any better way to do it.

```css
.btn {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #d9296f;
  border: 0.2rem solid #d9296f;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #d9296f;
  color: #08122f;
}
```

```html
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="content"><span data aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="150">Hi, I'm Emilia</span>
    <h3 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">Your Web Developer</h3>
    <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="450">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit ametconsectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur doloremque eius sit ratione eveniet laborum inventore recusandae consequuntur ipsum, nostrum aspernatur, ab, libero quos natus iusto et quasi sed est!</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-aos="flip-up" data-aos-delay="600">about me</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already use, you can use the anchor. You just have to use `#id` as hyper reference such as: `<a href="#id-of-section">Button Name</a>`. This will move your site to the elemnt with that `id`. The default behavior is an instant jump which you can change to scroll by using: `scroll-behavior: smooth;`

```css
/* only for styling purpose - no actual use */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section id="section-1">
  <h1>This is Section 1</h1>
  <a href="#section-2">Go to Section 2</a>
</section>
<section id="section-2">
  <h1>This is Section 2</h1>
  <a href="#section-3">Go to Section 3</a>
</section>
<section id="section-3">
  <h1>This is Section 3</h1>
  <a href="#section-4">Go to Section 4</a>
</section>
<section id="section-4">
  <h1>This is Section 4</h1>
  <a href="#section-1">Go to Section 1</a>
</section>
```